# How to solve equations like $2^n = 9... ?$

Tags: optimization, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, decimal-expansion, fractional-part

Consider natural powers of $2$ and their first $k$ digits.

For example find the smallest natural number ( positieve integer ) $n$ such that :

$$2^n = 3...$$

Is solved by $2^5 = 32 $ and thus $n=5$.

The title asks for

$$ 2^n = 9...$$

I think $n=53$ is the smallest solution.
But the main point here is how to efficiently solve these questions.

As a sidenote I wonder why considering first digits instead of last ( mod ) is not seen more often in Number theory.

Anyways here is what i considered but im not sure this is an improvement over simple brute force search.

Let $<*>$ denote fractional part.
( example $<e> = 0,71828...$ )

$2^n = 9...$

$ 10^{ log(2) n} = 9 * 10^{s} $

$ 10^{log(2) n} = 10^{s + log(9)} $

$ log(2) n - log(9) = s $

$ < log(2) n - log(9) > < log(10/9) $

$ < log(2) n - log(9) > < 1 - log(9) $

And this happens at $n = 53$.

Probably all this can be simplified alot and be solved more efficiently.

I assume logarithms and digits of logarithms are key ??

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but at least want to let you know that you've (re)discovered what is called Benford's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law.

Comment: I do not know how to do this in general, but for this question I will try to claim something like "$2^{10} \approx 10^3$" and "8 is the closest to 9 among $2^0, 2^1, \cdots, 2^9$."

Comment: Yes but using $2^{10}$ as close to $10^3$ does not Get us $2^{53} = 9...$ at all ?

Comment: By multiplying 8 by $2^{10}$ recursively you will eventually get a number which starts at 9.

Comment: That is Just equivalent to saying $53 = 5 * 10 + 3 $. We Also Get the answer by multiplying recursively by 2 :) I guess in Some cases this strategy might work but consider $2^m = 31415...$ or even $2^c= 7...$.

Comment: Also Remember we consider the minimum solution , not Just any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logarithms and *continued fractions* are the key. If $2^n$ starts with a $9$, we have that
$$ 2^n = (9+\theta)\cdot 10^m , \qquad \theta\in[0,1)$$
$$ n\log(2) = m\log(10) + \log(9+\theta) $$
$$ n = m\log_2(10) +\log_2(9+\theta) $$
$$ \frac{n}{m}-\log_2(10) = \frac{\log_2(9+\theta)}{m} $$
$$ \frac{\log_2(9)}{m}\leq \frac{n}{m}-\log_2(10) \leq \frac{\log_2(10)}{m} \tag{A}$$
and we may solve $(A)$ by studying the (best) rational approximations of the constant 
$$ \log_{2}(10)=3.321928\ldots=[3; 3, 9, 2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 18, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 42,\ldots]. $$
For instance, by truncating the continued fraction at the fourth term we get that $0\leq \frac{196}{59}-\log_2(10)\leq \frac{1}{59^2}$, and by interpolating contiguous convergents we may find all the solutions of $(A)$. In our case $53-15\log_2(10)$ belongs to the range $(\log_2(9),\log_2(10))$ and it gives the minimal solution, so $2^{53}$ is the first power of $2$ whose decimal representation begins with the digit $9$.

Comment: As I currently understand it , this method ( for the general case not Just the title case ) finds solutions $n$ that work but not always the smallest one ? Right ?

Comment: @mick: if you just pick a convergent and sligthly tweak it you get a solution, which is not granted to be the smallest one. On the other hand, by considering ratios of the form $\frac{p_n+\eta\, p_{n+1}}{q_n+\eta\, q_{n+1}}$, with $\eta\in[0,1]$ and $\frac{p_n}{q_n},\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}$ being consecutive convergents, you may find the smallest solution, too.